# Creating CombineFileSplit in Java of Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, filesplitting

CombineFileSplit  has a constructor:

```
CombineFileSplit(Path[] files, long[] start, long[] lengths, String[] locations)
```

is it necessary for the locations array to be the same size as files array, because the file can reside in many locations/nodes?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary that the locations array to be the same size as files array, because from the FileSplit's constructor:
public FileSplit(Path file,
                 long start,
                 long length,
                 String[] hosts)
you can conclude that a file can have many locations/hosts. Also if you see the source code of the constructor of CombineFileSplit, you can pass an array of empty strings. I think the locations array is meant to be used by you so if you know the locations of the file that's it you can provide it or pass empty strings.